# Using elm-css with elm-mdl

Tags: css, elm

I am trying to style an `elm-mdl` component using `elm-css` attributes:

```
Button.render Mdl
  [ 5 ]
  model.mdl
  [ Button.colored
  , Button.raised
  , Button.ripple
  , marginRight (px 20)
  ]
  [ text "Register" |> toUnstyled ]
  |> fromUnstyled
```

but the line `marginRight (px 20)` generates an error because the `Button` expects a `Button.Property m` and `marginRight (px 20)` is a `Style`.

Is there any sequence of function calls that can convert a CSS style created by `elm-css` so that it is usable by `elm-mdl`?

For now, I'm using `Material.Options.css "margin-right" "20px"`, but wuold prefer to use `elm-css` for the type safety.

Comment: There's http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-css/12.0.0/Css#asPairsDEPRECATED but it's deprecated now. I'm not sure if the functionality that replaced this function supports extracting raw CSS. I couldn't find it from a quick search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Richard Feldman, the author of the `elm-css` package, this is not possible: https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css/issues/336

Comment: It's worth noting that he says it's impossible to go to `( String, String )`, but with `Material.Options.attribute` you could get it working if it was possible to get an `Html.Attrbiute` from `elm-css`, which might be more possible, although the fact that type isn't used internally does imply that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
toMdlCss : Attribute a -> Material.Options.Property c a
toMdlCss a =
    Material.Options.attribute a
```

then: `toMdlCss <| style [( "padding", "10px" )]`